Flutter error : Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
i have upgraded flutter to the newest version but getting this error now.
`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

error: invalid source release: 17


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
`
I have tried building clean and deleting .gradle folder, still not working

I was getting the same error after flutter upgrade. What solved the problem for me was to update Android Studio to the latest version. Hope it will solve your problem too

The problem was solved by updating Android Studio to the latest version

hi you need to check you jdk version from  android/build.gradle file, you can set the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility to match your Java version
